# mySQL Wordpress filtering in separate rows with same ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have spent a long time trawling through the internet to try and find an answer to what I'm hoping will have an easy solution :-)

I have a booking system in which I need to be able to check whether a new booking conflicts with an existing booking. Booking start/end dates are stored in the wp_postmeta table which is causing an issue (I am modifying an existing plugin to my needs) when it comes to checking whether or not a booking conflicts as the results are stored in separate rows.

My select query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `wp_terms`.`term_id`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
FROM `wp_posts`
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` on `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `wp_posts`.`ID`
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_terms` on `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_terms`.`term_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` on `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id`
WHERE (`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` like 'fc_start' or `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` like 'fc_end') AND (`wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'meter') AND (`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'events')
```

this returns the correct results which are as follows: The ID field represents the booking which is a custom post type. The term_id represents one or items which can be booked out under that booking and the meta_key/value fields represent the start and end time of the particular booking.

```
ID  term_id meta_key    meta_value
6   8       fc_start    2013-12-21
6   8       fc_end      2013-12-23
23  9       fc_start    2013-12-17
23  9       fc_end      2013-12-28
33  8       fc_start    2013-12-01
33  8       fc_end      2013-12-19
39  8       fc_start    2014-01-04
39  8       fc_end      2014-01-17
39  9       fc_start    2014-01-04
39  9       fc_end      2014-01-17
```

This all works great, however, now I need to check whether a new booking overlaps an existing booking where the same items are booked out i.e. it is ok to have bookings overlap, as long as they don't contain the same items (term_id).

I have tried modifying the query as shown below, however, this doesn't seem to grab the correct start/end dates of each booking. For example, with the query below, I can't book out items 8 or 9 (term_id) from the 2nd - 3rd Jan 2014 as the query returns the start date of a previous booking and an end date of another.

I wondered whether or not I could achieve this through the WHERE clause however this wouldn't allow the use of GROUP_CONCAT. The variables $start, $end are submitted through a form.

I am expecting the bookings which **DO** overlap to be returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ID`, `wp_terms`.`term_id`,`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`
FROM `wp_posts`
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` on `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `wp_posts`.`ID`
INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_terms` on `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_terms`.`term_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` on `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id`
WHERE (`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` like 'fc_start' or `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` like 'fc_end') AND (`wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'meter') AND (`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'events')
GROUP BY `ID`
HAVING  (STR_TO_DATE(('" .$start. "'), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`),19), '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(GROUP_CONCAT(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`),19), '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')) OR
(STR_TO_DATE(('" .$end. "'), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`),19), '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(GROUP_CONCAT(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`),19), '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y')) OR
(STR_TO_DATE(('" .$start. "'), '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`),19), '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(('" .$end. "'), '%d-%m-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(RIGHT(GROUP_CONCAT(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`),19), '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Hopefully this is a real simple one which will make me look stupid ;-)
Thanks in advance

*EDIT: I have created an sqlfiddle here sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931b7/5 I need to supply the query with my two variables $start and $end and return only the POST_ID(s) which overlap. I have selected extra fields in the query for your info, however, I only require the POST_ID in the end result.For instance, if I was to supply the query with 01-Dec-2013 and 07-Dec-2013, I would expect to return TERM_ID 8 as it is already booked out between 1-Dec and 19-Dec. If I was to supply 02-Jan-2014 and 03-Jan-2014, I would expect no POST_ID's returned. Hope this makes sense*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I have created an sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931b7/5    I need to supply the query with my two variables $start and $end and return only the POST_ID(s) which overlap. I have selected extra fields in the query for your info, however, I only require the POST_ID in the end result.For instance, if I was to supply the query with 01-Dec-2013 and 07-Dec-2013, I would expect to return TERM_ID 8 as it is already booked out between 1-Dec and 19-Dec. If I was to supply 02-Jan-2014 and 03-Jan-2014, I would expect no POST_ID's returned. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
   SELECT p.id
        , t.term_id
        , MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'fc_start' THEN pm.meta_value END) fc_start
        , MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'fc_end' THEN pm.meta_value END) fc_end
     FROM wp_posts p
     JOIN wp_postmeta pm
       ON pm.post_id = p.id
     JOIN wp_term_relationships tp
       ON tp.object_id = p.id
     JOIN wp_terms t 
       ON t.term_id = tp.term_taxonomy_id
    GROUP 
       BY p.id,t.term_id
   HAVING fc_start <= '2013-12-07'  
      AND fc_end   >= '2013-12-01';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931b7/15

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly!! I added a few more conditions in the HAVING clause so that it picks up those which overlap just the start or end date, but other than that, it's perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: if an existing meter (8) is booked out between 5-10th December, I need to check the new booking doesn't fall within those dates as you supplied, but also that the new booking doesn't span just the start or end date. So for example, a new booking 6-9th December would return (8) as it is already booked out, but also a booking for 4th-6th Dec would return (8) as would a booking for 9th-11th Dec. I added two more conditions and it works fine. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Yes, it definitely works as I intended it to, I have tested with a wide range of dates and it all works fine. On the front-end, I needed a way for the user to check the availability of a meter. A user specifies the dates they would like to book the meter for, the query then checks whether a meter has been booked out for ANY portion of that date range and returns the results to the user. I have checked every scenario and it all works great.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle you provided and change the start date to 30-Nov-2013 and keep the end date at 07-Dec-2013, nothing is returned as the date range provided now doesn't sit BETWEEN any current booking. I therefore added some extra conditions to take this into account as the meter is in use between the dates provided, albeit for one day.

Comment: ah, I see... I was plugging the fc_start <= start date rather than end. I did get to the same answer but yours is more elegant so will change. Thanks for your help and patience, much appreciated.